# Is it possible to convert while selecting in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

I have a simple SQL query but the input parameter is a string of multiple values. I'm trying to get this to work but maybe my syntax is off or it's not possible like this?

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table
WHERE CatID IN 
(SELECT CONVERT(TINYINT,value) FROM STRING_SPLIT(@Cat,'+'))
```

where `@Cat = '13+14+15'` and `CatID` is of type *tinyint*. I've also tried using `CONVERT(TINYINT,*)` without luck.
Previously I was using the following code but was hoping to switch it around because of other complications.

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table
WHERE CatID IN 
(CONVERT(NVARCHAR, CatID) IN (SELECT * FROM STRING_SPLIT(@Cat,'+'))
```

If there's another way to do this I'm open to suggestions, maybe someway to split directly into integers? Thanks!

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: I apologize, the error was elsewhere upstream it turns out. The code is working as expected it seems.

Answer (score 1):

It would be nice if you could specify what to call the argument for `string_split()` using an alias in the `FROM` clause:

```
SELECT t.* 
FROM Table t
WHERE t.CatID IN (SELECT CONVERT(TINYINT, val)
                  FROM STRING_SPLIT(@Cat, '+') ss(val)
                 );
```

But the grammar doesn't seem to allow that.  Your subquery solution seems like the better solution, although I would wrap that in a CTE.

You can split directly into integers, using a recursive CTE:

```
with cte as (
       select convert(tinyint, left(@cat + '+', charindex('+', @cat) - 1)) as val,
              substring(@cat, charindex('+', @cat + '+') + 1, len(@cat)) as rest
       union all
       select convert(tinyint, left(rest + '+', charindex('+', rest) - 1)),
              substring(rest, charindex('+', rest + '+') + 1, len(rest))
       from cte
      )
select t.*
from table t
where t.catid in (select val from cte);
```

Well, I'm not sure if this is "direct", but it doesn't require a UDF.

Comment: I am trying to use the ss(val) but it's giving me an error on that. `'STRING_SPLIT' is not a recognized function name.`

Comment: @MuffinMan . . . I'm using the syntax from your question.  You can download a string split function easily (google "sql server string split").  When calling a function, you need to include the schema name.

Comment: `STRING_SPLIT` is a built in function if they are on 2016.

Comment: @GordonLinoff STRING_SPLIT works fine but as soon as I add ss(val) after, it gives that error. I even tried copying/pasting your first code block, same error.

Comment: @MartinSmith I am running 2016.

Comment: @MuffinMan yep. `SELECT CONVERT(TINYINT, value) FROM STRING_SPLIT(@Cat, '+') ss` works fine but the grammar doesn't allow the column to be aliased. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177634.aspx

Comment: @MartinSmith . . . . Any reason why `@variable.function_call` allows an alias but user defined aliases do not?